# Fantasy novel about a warrior woman with a golden hand?

Tags: story-identification, novel, magical-items

I need help identifying a fantasy novel i read in the late 90s, about a woman with a magic gold hand?

In 98 or so I read a hardback fantasy novel that I can't remember the author or title for.

It featured a warrior woman who was captured by the big bad, and sent to his prison / mine. The Big Bad would lop off a limb of each of the prisoners, then force them to mine some magical golden material.

The main character woman was apparently a mage of some sort as well, and she managed to scrape up enough of the raw golden material to form herself a new hand out of it. Armed with her hand she manages to escape!

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean *[The Warrior Returns](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1019568.The_Warrior_Returns)* by Allen Cole

The author's website [has an excerpt from the first chapter](http://www.acole.com/novels/anteros/warrior.html) that includes this passage (emphasis mine):

> My left arm throbbed and I groaned from the ghost pain. The pain made me angrier still. I'd sacrificed an eye and a hand for my goddess and my people. A golden eyepatch covered the right socket and a small scar cut that same cheek. I had a **magical golden hand** in place of the living one, **which I'd lost in the mines of Koronos**.